# How to determine a tenant's invitation policies?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

How could I use AAD Graph API to determine whether guest invitations are allowed for a tenant?  Specifically I'm looking for information about how to attain the settings listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-b2b-delegate-invitations#control-who-can-invite.[image: User Setting Page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, both Azure AD Graph and Microsoft Graph doesn't support this feature at present. If you want this feature in the future, you can submit the feedback from [Feedback for Azure Active Directory](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory) or [Feedback for Microsoft Graph](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis).

Comment: I confirmed with AAD team directly, there is no public API to get this data.